# HP printer will print and scan from browser but not from printing utility

Tags: printing, printer, connection, network-printer

I am trying to fix a friends printing issues with his HP Envy 5530.

He switched internet provider earlier this week and since then he has not been able to scan or print.

His computer is on a wired connection, his printer is wireless.

I have managed to get it to print diagnostics pages via the printer IP page through the browser on the computer he is trying to print from, and also scanning works fine via that page.

I have power cycled the computer, printer and router; reinstalled printer drivers and re-run the wireless setup utility.

It is not possible to connect the printer with a wire apparently (probably lost the wire).

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: How about you add a printer and then assign a port to it, you already have printers IP or assign a static IP to printer

Comment: First you add a printer without searching it, then choose the correct driver and install it, once added go into its properties and add/configure TCP/IP port.

Comment: Add this as an answer and i'll mark is as correct. It worked thank you so much! @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you can access printer via browser over its IP and driver is installed.

You can follow the steps below and printer should be ready to use again

1. Click on Start
2. Devices & Printers
3. Add a printer
4. Click on Add a network, wireless or Bluetooth Printer
5. Stop the printer search → The printer I want isn't listed
6. Add a printer using a TCP/IP address or hostname & Click Next
7. Enter Hostname/IP address of printer and Click Next
8. Select the driver for printer from the list or insert Disk
9. Enter printer name & Click Next
10. Wait for the installation to finish